# adding errors to model in rails is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

Ok this is not making sense. I can add an error to the model, but when I call valid? or save! it deletes the error that I added. However, the regular validations will prevent model from being saved. Why isn't errors.add working?

```
1.9.3p0 :001 > @order = Order.new(email: 'some@email.com')
 => #<Order id: nil, name: nil, address: nil, email: "some@email.com", pay_type: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, paypal_customer_token: nil, paypal_recurring_profile_token: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, account_details: {}, unit_id_for_plan: nil, invoice: nil, purchased_at: nil> 
1.9.3p0 :002 > @order.valid?
 => true 
1.9.3p0 :003 > @order.errors.add :base, 'error'
 => ["error"] 
1.9.3p0 :004 > @order.errors.size
 => 1 
1.9.3p0 :005 > @order.valid?
 => true 
1.9.3p0 :006 > @order.errors.size
 => 0 
1.9.3p0 :007 > @order.errors.add :base, 'error_again'
 => ["error_again"] 
1.9.3p0 :008 > @order.errors.size
 => 1 
1.9.3p0 :009 > @order.save!
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `orders` (`account_details`, `address`, `created_at`, `email`, `first_name`, `invoice`, `last_name`, `name`, `pay_type`, `paypal_customer_token`, `paypal_recurring_profile_token`, `purchased_at`, `unit_id_for_plan`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('--- {}\n', NULL, '2013-05-23 18:17:18', 'some@email.com', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2013-05-23 18:17:18')
   (12.6ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
1.9.3p0 :010 > @order.errors.size
 => 0
```

The Order model doesn't contain much validation:

```
  attr_accessible :address, :email, :name, :pay_type, :paypal_customer_token, :paypal_payment_token, :first_name, :last_name, :account_details, :invoice
  has_one :cart
  has_many :line_items, :through => :cart
  has_many :products, :through => :line_items, :source => :sellable, :source_type => 'Product'
  has_many :airtime_plans, :through => :line_items, :source => :sellable, :source_type => 'AirtimePlan'
  has_many :payment_notifications

  serialize :account_details, Hash  

  validates_presence_of :email
```

The validates_presence_of :email correctly will prevent save from working, but when I use errors.add :base, it doesn't work.

@LeoCorrea answer led me to come up with this solution:

```
validate :user_validation, :on => :create
attr_accessor :users_invalid

def user_validation
  if users_invalid
    errors[:base] << "You have invalid user records"
  end
end 

#paypal_payment model in which the order is passed into
elsif resp["status"] == "error"
    #@order.errors.add(:base, resp["body"])
    @order.users_invalid = true
end
```

The problem is the actual error message I want is in resp["body"]. Right now I just added an unhelpful message "You have invalid user records".

Comment: we need your full `save_with_payment` method I think

Comment: @user1737909 I added the full method

Comment: And your validators... One thing I noticed though, in your methods you're using `save!`, which throws an exception on error, instead of `save`, which returns true/false. But I think that's secondary, I would check your validations first.

Comment: @dpassage I updated question. This is not even working in the console.

Comment: I think you need to add errors during the validation phase. After the fact is too late.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`valid?` on a AR model clears the errors array, it does not check for whether you have errors in the errors array or not. As for `save!` it runs validations which have nothing to do with the errors array. If you want to have errors in your model, you need to add validations to it.

If you read the code for `valid?` this is what you'll see

**ActiveRecord::Validations**

```
def valid?(context = nil)
  context ||= (new_record? ? :create : :update)
  output = super(context)
  errors.empty? && output
end
```

The call of `super(context)` is just a call to `ActiveModel::Validations#valid?` which is the one responsible for clearing the errors array before running validations:

**ActiveModel::Validations**

```
def valid?(context = nil)
  current_context, self.validation_context = validation_context, context
  errors.clear
  run_validations!
ensure
  self.validation_context = current_context
end
```

**UPDATE**

In order to add your custom errors, you have to do it on a validation method which adds it when the validation is checked. Anything before or after will just be cleared when you re-run validations.

Take a look at this resource http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#errors

The errors are added on a method that is called with validation.

Comment: ok so because I have to add the error in a completely different model, that means I have to create an attr_accessor and set it to true. And then create a custom validation and check if that attr_accessor is set to true, and if true, then add to errors[:base]. But that still raises an issue in that by that point, I wont know what the actual error messages are.

Comment: I don't follow you...what case would you have to add the error from another model? That'd just make those two models tightly coupled.

Comment: What exactly is it that you need to do or in what case do you need to add the errors? Update your answer to answer that.

Comment: paypal_payment model is not a rails model. It is used for paypal functionality but has no database or anything.

Comment: I guess my question is what would be the use of adding errors to the @orders instance if you're just going to re-validate it or try to save it later on? If the response from paypal is invalid you should just relay that information back to the user? I get the idea of what you're trying to do I just don't see your entire implementation so I can't comment much on it.

Comment: The issue is that now your paypal_payment model is now tightly coupled with your order model

Comment: "If the response from paypal is invalid you should just relay that information back to the user? " That's a good point. The only thing with that is that the controller is orders/create here, so it runs a if @order.save (and redirects to page on success or renders orders/new on validation error). Thats why I thought of adding validation to order model.

Comment: Then who's calling the paypal_payment model? The controller or the Order model?

Comment: The order model calls a method called save_with_payment: @order.save_with_payment. save_with_payment calls a method called paypal, which passes the order object into it: PaypalPayment.new(self). And then a method is called on that now paypalpayment object which handles a lot of paypal stuff that uses some of the order information. But the response is what is going to determine whether the order model saves or not.